# How to map corresponding values of a 2D NumPy array into an 1D array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization

I have written this piece of code:

```py
data = np.array([[3,6], [5,9], [4, 8]])

orig_x, orig_y = np.split(data, 2, axis=1)

x = np.array([3, 4])
y = np.zeros((len(x)))

for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = orig_y[np.where(orig_x == x[i])[0]]
```

So basically, I have a 2D NumPy array. I split it into two 1D arrays orig_x and orig_y, one storing values of the x-axis and the other values of the y-axis.

I also have another 1D NumPy array, which has some of the values that exist in the orig_x array. I want to find the y-axis values for each value in the x array. I created this method, using a simple loop, but it is extremely slow since I'm using it with thousands of values.

Do you have a better idea? Maybe by using a NumPy function?

Note: Also a better title for this question can be made. Sorry :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a mask over which values you want from the x column and then use this mask to select values from the y column.

```
data = np.array([[3,6], [5,9], [4, 8]])

# the values you want to lookup on the x-axis
x = np.array([3, 4])

mask = np.isin(data[:,0], x)
data[mask,1]
```

Output:

```
array([6, 8])
```

The key function here is to use `np.isin`. What this is basically doing is broadcasting `x` or `data` to the appropriate shape and doing an element-wise comparison:

```
mask = data[:,0,None] == x
y_mask = np.logical_or.reduce(mask, axis=1)
data[y_mask, 1]
```

Output:

```
array([6, 8])
```

Comment: This is a very fast solution, but I think it returns the values out of order (not following the order of the elements of `x`). It's not clear from the OP if the order matters.

Comment: @Seb the mask is ordered on the elements of ```x``` which is the same order as elements in ```y```.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the problem correctly, but I think the following should work:

```py
>>> rows, cols = np.where(orig_x == x)
>>> y = orig_y[rows[np.argsort(cols)]].ravel()
>>> y
array([6, 8])
```

It assumes that all the values in `orig_x` are unique, but since your code example has the same restriction, I considered it a given.

Comment: Yes, I wanted something like this exactly, and the values in orig_x are unique, but it didn't seem to make it any faster. Maybe there is no solution to optimize it.

Comment: I'd like to do some timing tests. How long are your `data` and `x` arrays?

Comment: The data I'm testing right now has about 500K values and the x array has about 10K. However, the data might vary from 100K to 10M. Also, I have two X arrays. X1 and X2 for each data array, so this makes it slower too.

Answer (score 0):

What about a lookup table?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[3,6], [5,9], [4, 8]])

orig_x, orig_y = np.split(data, 2, axis=1)

x = np.array([3, 4])
y = np.zeros((len(x)))
```

You can pack a dict for lookup:

```
lookup = {i: j for i, j in zip(orig_x.ravel(), orig_y.ravel())}
```

And just map this into a new array:

```
np.fromiter(map(lambda i: lookup.get(i, np.nan), x), dtype=int, count=len(x))
array([6, 8])
```

If `orig_x` & `orig_y` are your smaller data structures this will probably be most efficient.

EDIT - It's occurred to me that if your values are integers the default `np.nan` won't work and you should figure out what value makes sense for your application if you're trying to find a value that isn't in your `orig_x` array.